# Is it possible to arrange commands properly on a GUI Element in iOS?

Tags: codenameone

In the properties of a GUI Element in theme.res it is possible to add commands. 
In Android, they are perfectly showed when the 3 dot button in the upper right corner is clicked. 
But on iOS, the buttons are scattered on the whole screen and not stored behind a decent button. 
Is it possible to arrange them properly in iOS? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Toolbar API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html) which is the official way moving forward.

It allows you to place commands in a way that is portable into a side menu, title area (left/right) overflow etc.